# How to stop Laravel 5 from caching configurations?

Tags: laravel-5

It is written in Laravel 5 documentation that `php artisan config:cache` stores all the app configuration into one single file which makes the application load faster.

I want to know two things:

The first thing is, how to force Laravel to stop caching my app configurations? For example, I want Laravel to read the name of my database and the password from the `.env` file or from the `database.php` configuration file, not from the cached data.

The second thing is, where does Laravel store this cached configuration file, so that I can delete it when needed? I know there is an Artisan command for that, which is `php artisan config:clear`, but I want to know where the file stored.

Comment: only solution is to not use artisan

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can't *stop* the caching of config files since it doesn't happen automatically. The only thing you need to do, is not call `config:cache`.

The file itself can be found in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

**Note** that the location of the compiled config file has changed recently. Yours might also be in `vendor/config.php` or `storage/framework/config.php`. With a fresh install or if you run `composer update` the file should be in `bootstrap/cache` though.

Comment: Work for me, it's hard coded in Laravel 5 , at [ vendor/config.php ]

Comment: If you did however call `config:cache` during local development, you can undo this by deleting the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. Otherwise, you might experience that calling `getenv()` will not return the desired values

Comment: We had this issue when we've added `config:cache` as post deployment hook in envoyer (for production server). Oddly enough, somehow it did not take all the values from the .env file.

Comment: Im using Laravel 5.6 and my config doesn't change even after `rm bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

Comment: I ended up doing `$config =require base_path('config/services.php');`. We've struggled with this a few times in the past. Only laravel can make something this simple problematic.

Comment: Calling `php artisan config:clear` will also fix the issue until you call `php artisan config:cache`. However if you have a large team... it may be wise just to instill some checkers to make sure the cache is always there and always up to date.

Answer (score -1):

As per the post here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2501

> "Change cache driver to array for the local environment."

For me this involves adding `CACHE_DRIVER=array` to my `.env` file. This is then picked up by my config/cache.php file which includes the line: 
`'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),`

Obviously you could change it directly in the config/cache.php but I'd prefer to use the .env file so I can disable it for development sites and enable for production.

Comment: This is completely unrelated. The settings in `config/cache.php` relate to Laravel's cache feature as documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/cache), which is *not* used when caching the configuration itself. The configuration is only ever cached in the form of PHP code inside `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.